# Instead of -applye-system, I tried to fallback SF Compact Rounded in the CSS on macOS

Tags: css, macos, font-face, webfonts

I would apply SF Compact Rounded which is already an Apple's macOS' pre-installed font, so I would switch from `-apple-system` to `SF Compact Rounded` as fallback font on CSS

```
      @font-face 
      {
        font-family: 'SF Compact Rounded';
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        src: local("SF Compact Rounded Regular"), local("SFCompactRounded-Regular");
      }

      @font-face 
      {
        font-family: 'SF Compact Rounded';
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: bold;
        src: local("SF Compact Rounded Bold"), local("SFCompactRounded-Bold");
      }
```

And I switched:

```
body {
   font-family: -apple-system, sans-serif;
}
```

to:

```
body {
   font-family: 'SF Compact Rounded', -apple-system, sans-serif;
}
```

But it does not work. I tried also `.SF-Compact-Rounded`, `SF-Compact-Rounded`, `.SF-NS-Rounded` and `SF-NS-Rounded`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try ".SF Compact Rounded".